# copy directory from network (or shared) path to local directory in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

How to do this can anyone help me
i also want some help in checking whether the directory exists in network path or not

`if(Directory::Exists(networkpath))` is not working either...

i have network path starting with'\somefolder\dir'
i tried this way

`if(Directory::Exists("\\\somefolder\\dir")`

no luck....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you posted has a single backslash before `dir`, that won't work because inside the string literal the backslash is treated as the first half of an escape character.

You need to use double backslashes for every single backslash in the undecorated filepath.

`if(Directory::Exists("\\\\somefolder\\dir")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my post i have given the original path. When i am checking with if(Directory::Exists(networpath)) i have given "\\\\somefolder\\dir", still doesn't work. at this step it is skipping, immediately going to else statements from if statement.

Comment: all the remaining code works ok, i have tested with local directory, when i chaged the path to network path it is not working and the directory exists in network path.

Comment: Try adding code to open a known file on the share, and see wat exception you get.  `Directory.Exists` swallows some exceptions.